# logstash extract matched strings into array

Tags: arrays, regex, logstash, logstash-configuration

In Logstash 1.5, in the event, there are multiple places that can matched my patterns, and I like to extract all the matched data into array to merge with another field, i.e., for mac, aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, i like to extract [aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff] as an array.  How could I do this?  and how to access the array data in logstash config?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [mutate->split{}](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-split) will create the array.